# Row span is not working as I expected, what I need to change here

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to print key in center of values.so that I tried to use rowspan but it's repeating n times.

here is my code

```
  <table >
                  <tbody ng-repeat="(key,value) in values1" >
                     <tr >
                        <th translate> Heading 1</th>
                        <th translate> Heading 2 </th>
                        <th  translate> Heading 3 </th>
                        <th  translate> Heading 4 </th>
                     </tr>

                     <tr ng-repeat="itr in value">

                        <td  >
                           {{itr .value1}}
                        </td>
                        <td  >
                           {{itr .value2}}
                        </td>
                        <td  >
                            {{itr .value3}}
                        </td>
                        <td rowspan="{{value.length+1}}" >
                           {{key}}
                        </td>
                  
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
```

But I am getting like this.

[image]

I need in this format
[image]

Comment: Where exactly you want to print the Oct 2021 in each line ?.

Comment: Oct 2021 should be printed only once like above image

Comment: Ok..then you don't need to print that in the loop. You might need to print that outside the loop

Comment: if i add <td> outside of the loop it prints month in  first column

Comment: Just like rowspan, you can use colspan to merge more than 2 cells vertically